# Как передать параметр в метод контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Продолжаю мучать ASP MVC. Возник вопрос - как передать в метод контроллера несколько параметров? Например сейчас у меня на `VIEW` есть ссылка :

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)item, "ConcretTable", new { id = item }, new { paper = 1 })
```

Которая должна передать в метод `ConcretTable` контроллера 2 параметра. Вот так выглядит сам `ConcretTable` :

```
    public ActionResult ConcretTable(string id, int paper)
    {
   // что то делаем
    return View();
    }
```

Вроде все просто но если запустить падает исключение :

> Словарь параметров содержит запись со значением NULL для параметра "paper" типа "System.Int32", не допускающего значение NULL, для метода "System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ConcretTable(System.String, Int32)" в "mvc_vechicle.Controllers.TableController". Необязательный параметр должен иметь ссылочный тип, тип, допускающий значение NULL, либо он должен быть объявлен как необязательный параметр.
>   Имя параметра: parameters

При этом если я уберу `paper` вообще оставив только :

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)item, "ConcretTable", new { id = item })
```

и

```
    public ActionResult ConcretTable(string id)
    {
   // что то делаем
    return View();
    }
```

Все начинает работать корректно - где я ошибся и что такое `parameters`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)item, "ConcretTable", new { id = item, paper = 1})
```

В параметрах передаешь сразу несколько нужных тебе значений.

Comment: Всего навсего. спасибо тебе добрый человек!!)